# ios vh on viewport orientation change

Tags: css, mobile-safari, viewport, viewport-units

It's weird iOS bug time again. I've got a header that's set to around 70vh, and (for the most part) it works well. It used to be buggy in iOS Safari but they seem to have fixed it. Apart from when you rotate the screen. It seems to double every time you rotate the viewport. 70vh becomes 140vh, then 210vh and so on.

I don't know if there's anything I can change in the CSS or on the meta viewport tag that will stop this? I'll even look entertain Javascript solutions if that's the only way around it.

[Here's](http://sam.beckham.io) the site I'm referencing. All the code is on [github](https://github.com/sambeckham/blog) if that's your thing.

Comment: Viewport height units was buggy indeed in IOS 7, but it was fixed in IOS8. I opened your [site](http://sam.beckham.io/) in mobile safari and rotated my iphone as crazy, but all works ok, your `header` with height: 72.2vh; always take 70% of screen. Are you using outdated IOS? Current version is 8.1.2.

Comment: Well that's a relief. I'm on iOS 7, I don't have access to iOS 8 at the moment so thanks for checking that. I'd still like to pop in a workaround for iOS 7 if I can though.

Comment: Actually, in IOS 7 container with height: xxvh can eat xx% of body instead, so other elements are become invisible. It looks like Apple won't patch this ever. There is *buggyfill* for it, but it works via parse all existing link[rel=stylesheet] tags, and fails on 3rd party CDNs because of cross-origin policy. There is more easy fix in case you have too few elements with vh on page: `if ((/(iPhone|iPod|iPad).+OS 7_/i).test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  // ios 7 viewport units bug
  $("#myheaderselectorhere").height(window.innerHeight);
 }; `

Comment: But this is "naive" approach, you'll need to adapt it to react on device orientation change of course.

Comment: Finally, check [this](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/34-iOS7-Mobile-Safari-And-Viewport-Units.html) article. It covers problem itself, quickfix similar to which I showed and buggyfill as well.